# How to fill RecyclerView (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) with images in correct scale type?

Tags: java, android, css, image, android-recyclerview

I got such issue with my RecyclerView

I need to present to user images that I downloaded with help of picasso lib from web to my RecyclerView. Eventually it looks like this

[image]

As you can see I need to scratch my images, but in proper aspect ratio of course.

I went to my XML file and set attribute in my `ImageView` `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

now my `ImageView` looks like this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMainCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
```

and here is result that I got

[image]

as you can see now image fill all available space, but them doesn't scratch with propriety aspect ratio. Images scratch width more than height and does't looks nice...

Also here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="3dp"
android:paddingEnd="3dp"
android:paddingStart="3dp"
android:paddingTop="3dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cardMainActivityLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

  <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
      android:id="@+id/rippleInbox"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/ntz_background_light_grey"
      app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
      >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMainCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

  </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/rlCardMain"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/white"
      android:padding="4dp"
      >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBrandName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black_color"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvBrandName"
        android:textColor="@color/black_color"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPreviousPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvItemName"
        android:textColor="@color/black_color"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDivider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvPreviousPrice"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvPreviousPrice"
        android:text=" / "
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvDivider"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvDivider"
        android:textColor="@color/black_color"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAction"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        />

  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit1**

There is a result of `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` attributes

[image]

It is also not so nice when women don't have head))

**Edit2**

There is result of `android:scaleType="centerInside"`

[image]

Comment: @PratikButani added screenshot in question according to your advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, please use centerCrop to center the image absolute  to it's parent. Also add this attribute, android:adjustViewBounds="true". With this the aspect ratio of the image will be preserved.

Comment: Yes! I don't know how down vote your answer , but It is exactly that I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`fitXY` uses `FILL` which is described as "Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This may change the aspect ratio of the src" in the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#FILL).

You should use `centerInside` to center, fit and scale while keeping the aspect ratio

Comment: what part of it doesn't work? it looks just like what you wanted :S

Comment: of course not, didn't you see that right and left borders of cell not the same with right and left borders of image?? Try to compare image from previous my screenshots with image that I got according to you advise. Do you see difference in width of image?

Comment: Actually it has no difference with my first screenshot

Comment: Of course yes. You're asking about the image fit, centerInside solves your image fit problem. They scale perfectly without breaking the aspect ratio, which is what you wanted. The light gray background has nothing to do with the image or its fit.

Comment: )) ok, let me explain to you more detail) I need to scale my image so, I need image take ALL space that available from cell, BUT I need that scale was with propriety aspect ratio... Take a look on my second screenshot. I need completely the same , BUT with propriety aspect ratio. Did you get my idea?

Answer (score 0):

Alright the problem is that your layout does not respect the bounds of your image.To remedy this, wrap the image-view in a separate parent layout , add a parent weight to the layout it self with layout_weight="1".Then set the width relative to the layout with android:layout_width="0px", to avoid tearing and proper bounds coordination set android:adjustViewBounds="true". To center and crop the image at it's center use android:scaleType="centerCrop".

Comment: Caspain how are you?)) Why are you answering twice for the same question?